# solving recurrence relation f(n)=f(n-1)+d

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I was wondering how to solve this  relation  $f(n)=f(n-1)+d$ 
with initial value $f(0)=a$

Comment: Evaluate $f(0)$ to $f(10)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with *arithmetic progressions*?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool i am, i know i should use complementary functions to solve it, but I am not getting to the solution while trying

Comment: Did you find $f(10)$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust you can't find it, the "d" and "a" are constant but you don't know their value

Comment: The homogeneous solution to $f(n)=f(n-1)+d$ is $f_h(n)=c$ where $c$ is constant, the particular solution is $f_p(n)=kn$ for some constant $k$.  Now find $c$ and $k$ in terms of the parameters given in the problem.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool That's the answer that I got, but the question suggests that inconsistency should appear after solving for the complementary function and the particular solution, so I thought I was getting something wrong with my solution

Comment: I am not sure, but perhaps the "inconsistency" refers to the form of the particular solution $f_p(n)=kn$.  Note that the original equation is $f(n)=f(n-1)+d=f(n-1)+d\cdot 1^n$.  Usually, you would take $f_p(n)=k=k\cdot 1^n$, but since the characteristic polynomial of the problem is $x-1$, which has $1$ as a root, you can't use $f_p(n)=k\cdot 1^n$, but $f_p(n)=kn\cdot 1^n=kn$ instead.

Comment: @HaithamIsmaill: sorry, this is not true. What's the value of $f(0)$ ? Of $f(1)$ ?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0):

For $n=0$ we have $a-d=f(-1)$ and for $n=1$ we have $a+d=f(1)$

So $d=\dfrac{f(1)-f(-1)}{2}$ and the relation becomes $f(n)=f(n-1)+\dfrac{f(1)-f(-1)}{2}$. This is the arithmetic progression with common difference $\dfrac{f(1)-f(-1)}{2}$.